# how to do webview and adjust text inside the form?

Tags: codenameone

I am new in codename one. I want to do the apps using webview. When I add the code below the simulator will close automotive. Here is the code:

```
 public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Login", new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER));
    hi.show();

    BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER);
    WebView web = new WebView();
    web.getEngine().load("http://google.com");
}
```

The socond question is how to set "Login" title to left and put image icon at the right side?

Answer (score 1):

`WebView` isn't a Codename One class. The Codename One class is `BrowserComponent`. I'm guessing you changed the classpath in the project in creative ways and probably the build script as well.

You can access native code with native interfaces but this isn't the way to do it.

Comment: can I know how to add an icon button at the upper right corner?

Comment: Use the toolbar accessible via the form. You can add a command to the right or left side.